# Asymmetric firmware encryption

Tags: embedded, rsa, cortex-m, firmware

My firmware is stored in an external flash memory chip which can be dumped.

To prevent this code from being reverse engineered/exploited, I would like to use asymmetric encryption but I do not know which algorithm to use.

My first though went to RSA. It has an implementation in ARM MBED, but it feels heavy for ciphering ~512k of firmware on Cortex-M3/4 by block of hundreds of bytes.

Is RSA suited for this kind of application considering keys are secure? Any other asymmetric encryption available?

Comment: RSA can not be used to encrypto more data that the key size (in detail the modulus length). Anyway why do you want to encrypt it asymmetrically? Where do you save the (private) decryption key. How do you execute the firmware if it is encrypted? These are the question you have to solve before deciding how to encrypt the firmware.

Comment: @Robert, usually the bootloader will load the external SW into the internal RAM. (e.g. per (Q)SPI). ... I would not do this without proper HW support. We did an authentication of an RSA2048 bit key, which tool like 85ms per verify on an e300z7 at 240MHz. You'd better stream this through some Crpyto-HW.

Comment: Generally, you'd use symmetric (AES) to encrypt the data, but the key to your AES encryption is exchanged assymetrically (RSA).  If you don't have super stringent boot time requirements, you should be able to key exchange and load 512KB of AES encrypted data with signature checking in less than 500mS

Comment: You must have a way to securely store a key that *cannot* be read by an attacker but *can* be read by your decryptor. Without that no encryption system, not RSA or AES or a hybrid system, will provide any security. Apple spends a phenomenal amount of money and has years of experience doing such proprietary designs.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and data. I considered that keys are secure: they are stored in a secure element such as SAM AV3 or ST33. Those secure elements offer HW for encryption, but it is often symmetric and the throughput is not high enough.